# Decrypt an RSA-message when it's encrypted by same modulus

Tags: cryptography

Suppose 2 entities have a different RSA key-pair, but have the same modulus n. Suppose also that a message M has been encrypted by both pairs. How can one recover M with a reasonable probability?

We know the public keys $e_1$ and $e_2$ of both entities, and we know $n$. From the RSA-algorithm, we also know that $gcd(e_1, \phi(n)) = 1$ and $gcd(e_2, \phi(n)) = 1$. Is it now possible to recover $phi(n)$ from these equations, or one of the private keys $d_1$ or $d_2$, or should I be looking at a completely different approach into solving this problem?

Comment: here one of ways is described: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack .

Comment: to find $s_1, s_2$ such that $e_1s_1+e_2s_2=1$, we can apply Extended Euclidean Algorithm. To be accurate, one of $s_1,s_2$ is negative, so we should apply calculation by modulo $\phi(n)$, i.e. to know this value too.

Comment: @Oleg567 Thank you. Can I be certain that $gcd(e_1, e_2) = 1$ given this information?

Comment: If $gcd(e_1,e_2)=1$, then we able to retrieve the message (see answer); but it can occur with low probability that $gcd(e_1,e_2)>1$, then described algorithm wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let we know $e_1, e_2$ and $n$.

And we know both ciphertexts $C_1 = M^{e_1}(\bmod n)$ an $C_2=M^{e_2} (\bmod n)$.

Then, assuming that $GCD(e_1,e_2)=1$, applying [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), it is easy to find $s_1,s_2$ such that $$e_1s_1+e_2s_2=1.$$
And therefore
$$C_1^{s_1}\cdot C_2^{s_2} \equiv M^{e_1s_1} \cdot M^{e_2s_2} \equiv M(\bmod n).\tag{1}$$

**Note 1:** one of the numbers $s_1, s_2$ is negative,
so it would be comfortable to know the value $$D\equiv C^{-1} (\bmod n)\tag{2}$$ previously for certain of ciphertexts.
We can easily derive this value from [EEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) too:
$$C\cdot D \equiv 1 (\bmod n),$$
$$C\cdot D - n \cdot L = 1,\tag{3}$$
i.e. for given pair $(C,n)$ (if $GCD(C,n)=1$) find coefficients $D,L$ for which $(3)$ holds.

**Note 2:** in the case when $GCD(e_1,e_2)\ne 1$ or $GCD(C,n)=1$ (which can occur theoretically, but with very small probability), this algorithm wouldn't work.

**Note 3:** if $GCD(C,n)\ne 1$, then this GCD coincides with one of factors of the number $n$: very lucky example, since we'll able to derive factors of $n$, and $\phi(n)$ instantly then.

**Example:** 
$n = 101\cdot103$.

 $e_1 = 5$, $e_2 = 13$.

$M = 64$ (unknown for us yet).

Then 
$C_1 = 64^5 \equiv 6582(\bmod 10403)$, 

$C_2 = 64^{13} \equiv 2445(\bmod 10403)$;

having $e_1=5,e_2=13$, we easily find $s_1 = -5,s_2=2$:
$$5\cdot (-5)+13\cdot 2 = 1,
$$

hence 
$$
M \equiv 6582^{-5} \cdot 2445^{2} (\bmod 10403).
$$
Find now value $D\equiv 6582^{-1} (\bmod 10403)$:
for given pair $(6582, 10403)$ find $D,L$ such that $(3)$ holds:
$$
6582\cdot(- 3327) + 10403\cdot 2105 = 1;
$$
we focus on the number $$D \equiv -3327  \equiv 7076 (\bmod 10403).$$

Then
$$
M \equiv 6582^{-5} \cdot 2445^{2} \equiv \\
7076^5 \cdot 2445^{2} \equiv \\
4746 \cdot 6703 \equiv  \\ 31812438 \equiv  64 (\bmod10403).
$$
Message $M$ is recovered.

**Example 2:** 

$n = 101\cdot103$.

 $e_1 = 7$, $e_2 = 14$.

 $\phi(n)=100\cdot 102 = 10200$;

 $GCD(e_1,\phi(n))=1$, $GCD(e_2,\phi(n))=1$, 

 but we have
$GCD(e_1,e_2)=7$,
so this algorithm wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I completely understand now

Comment: You're welcome. That's nice.